# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 php

Tags: error-handling

I'm getting the error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" on this part of  my code (posted below) and I'm not sure why. Let me know if you have any insight on how I can fix this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Boatsales (Dealer, Model, Floorplan, Tubedia, Centtubedia, Intcolor, Wallcolor, 2ndWallcolor, Furncolor, Prerig,
```

Motor, Chair, Waveglider, fivesevenpackage, Waveshield, Hpp, Vinylteak, Vinylfloor, Snapcarpet, Garmin200, Garmin500, Garmin431, Sidekeel, 
Skitow, Helmraised, Privacystation, Platinumpackage, Skistorage, Playpencover, Seatcover, Mooringcover, Dualbimini, Docklight, Underwaterlight,
 Moodlight, Delivery, Notes)

```
VALUES ('$Dealer',
```

'$Model',
'$Floorplan',
'$Tubedia',
'$Centtubedia',
'$Intcolor',
'$Wallcolor',
'$SecondWallcolor',
'$Furncolor',
'$Prerig',
'$Motor',
'$Chair',
'$Waveglider',
'$fivesevenpackage',
'$Waveshield',
'$Hpp',
'$Vinylteak',
'$Vinylfloor',
'$Snapcarpet',
'$Garmin200',
'$Garmin500',
'$Garmin431',
'$Sidekeel',
'$Skitow',
'$Helmraised',
'$Privacystation',
'$Platinumpackage',
'$Skistorage',
'$Playpencover',
'$Seatcover',
'$Mooringcover',
'$Dualbimini',
'$Docklight',
'$Underwaterlight',
'$Moodlight'
'$Delivery',
'$Motor')";

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma after `'$Moodlight'`

Also, strongly consider using prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php